# Does REST API version define resource structure, URI path or both

Tags: rest

I'm wondering what REST API version defines - resource structure, URI path or both? To me, it seems that specifying version in URI like this can define both:

```
api.foo.com/v1/path/to/resource
```

While specifying version as part of mime-type:

```
Content-type: application/json;application,v1
```

Clearly defines resource representation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some time ago I've read that the URL of a particular resource should not change among versions. After some thinking about it makes deep sense. URL is used to define an *unique* resource on the internet. If you specify version in URL it makes two *different* resources when it comes to definition above. Such resources may be a little different (a new field was added e.g.) however they seem to be exactly the same. Since then I use only header versioning.

Answer (score 1):

Its completely up to us, how we want to represent and implement API. To me also it seems that specifying version in URI defines both "Version" as well as "Resource" present in current API version or not.